# Load objects for the map based on current view bounds

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Rails web app with a Google map, which shows markers from a Mongoid database.

The amount of markers is really high and loading them all at once is very time and resource-consuming. Because of that, I'm loading the objects based on the map's current view bounds, but there is one problem:

New objects need to be loaded when the bounds change (`bounds_changed` event), but I don't want to add duplicate markers. I haven't found any way of doing this except creating an index of all the loaded objects and then comparing every loaded object with that. But I think there can be a more efficient way.

https://github.com/shvelo/pathfinder
https://github.com/shvelo/pathfinder/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/client.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the *bounds_changed* event in your git repo, but you're pretty much doing it right from what I can gather. Example:

```
var loaded = {"markerID1":true, "markerID2":true, ...};

if(!(marker in loaded)){
//Do stuff
}
```

No better way as of now. Although, ECMAScript 6 will soon the new standard, and it implements a real Set object.

Comment: `loaded[marker]` is slightly faster than `marker in loaded` , so I'm using that